# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I get this error,

```
 Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

when I am trying to project from a **custom type to a DateTime arrays**, please note `DateCreated` is of type `DateTime`.

Any idea how to solve it?

```
           DateTime[] data = analyticRepo.GetAll()
                                      .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) == report.DateCreated.Date)
                                      .Select(x => new DateTime(
                                          x.DateCreated.Year,
                                          x.DateCreated.Month,
                                          x.DateCreated.Day,
                                          x.DateCreated.Hour,
                                          x.DateCreated.Minute,
                                          x.DateCreated.Second,
                                          x.DateCreated.Millisecond))
                                      .ToArray();
```

Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x.DateCreated` is already a `DateTime`, just select *that*:

```
DateTime[] data = analyticRepo.GetAll()
                              .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) == report.DateCreated.Date)
                              .Select(x => x.DateCreated)
                              .ToArray();
```

Otherwise you'd have to use `AsEnumerable` to switch to a Linq-to-Objects context, *then* create new `DateTime` objects:

```
DateTime[] data = analyticRepo.GetAll()
                              .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) == report.DateCreated.Date)
                              .Select(x => x.DateCreated)
                              .AsEnumerable() // transition to Linq-to-Objects
                              .Select(x => new DateTime(
                                  x.Year,
                                  x.Month,
                                  x.Day,
                                  x.Hour,
                                  x.Minute,
                                  x.Second,
                                  x.Millisecond))
                              .ToArray();
```